# How to build a list of function calls from a library?

Tags: python, list

I need to build the value for a key in a dictionary. I want the value of this key to be a list. I need every element of the list to be the result of calling a library function with three floating point values.

I have the three floating point values for each element in a separate list as a list of lists. Is there an easy (or any) way to do this? Sample input and output would look like this:

Input:

```
 list_of_floats = [[float_1, float_2, float_3],
                   [float_4, float_5, float_6],
                   ...
                   [float_n-2, float_n-1, float_n]]
```

Output:

```
 dictionary = {"key": [library.function(float_1, float_2, float_3),
                       library.function(float_4, float_5, float_6),
                       ...
                       library.function(float_n-2,float_n-1,float_n)]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create the value list very simply using a list comprehension. This is a textbook case of its usage, really. Star parameter expansion will help you make the calls short:

```
dictionary = {'key': [library.function(*nums) for nums in list_of_floats]}
```

You could also plug this into [`itertools.starmap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap), which is the star-expanding analogue of the built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
dictionary = {'key': list(starmap(library.function, list_of_floats))}
```

You could even use `map` itself, but that would be a little bit more awkward, since you'll need a `lambda` or equivalent to do the expansion:

```
dictionary = {'key': list(map(lambda nums: library.function(*nums), list_of_floats))}
```

Comment: `starmap` is perfect for this. I wouldn't even bother mentioning `map`, since it's so much more cumbersome than the others.

Comment: @Barmar. Agreed. I like to be unnecessarily thorough, though I did put it last. I really think the comprehension is best overall. I'm not a big fan of maps in Python.

Comment: Thanks Everyone!

I might not be implementing the starmap solution properly. I need to import the itertools library and write the line as:  <br/>

'dictionary = {'key': list(itertools.starmap(library.function(), list_of_floats))}'  <br/>

right? Or am I doing something wrong? I am referring to this documentation:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: Clarification for my previous comment (since it won't let me edit anymore). The line of code is only - dictionary = {'key': list(itertools.starmap(library.function(), list_of_floats))} - and nothing else. I was just trying to write it as code in overflow but I am still trying to figure out how to do that.

Comment: @J_Aero_Paul. Yes, you need to `import itertools` and use `itertools.starmap`, or better yet, `from itertools import starmap`, and use just `starmap`. To post nice looking code, use backticks (`\``) and semicolon for linebreaks in python

Answer (score 0):

```
dictionary = {"key": []}

def iterate_list(l):

    param = []

    for item in l:
        if isinstance(item, list):
            iterate_list(item)
        else:
            param.append(item)

    dictionary["key"].append(library.function(*param))
```

Comment: There's nothing in the question suggesting that recursion is needed. It's just a 2-dimensional list, always with 3 floats in the second dimension.

Comment: The input list in the original question is a multi-level list. Check the editing history.

Comment: No, it was always a 2-level list. I did some formatting to make it more readable, but I didn't change the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list comprehension and call the function with argument spreading.

```
dictionary = {"key": library.function(*vals) for vals in list_of_floats)]
```

Comment: Expansion seems more prevalent than spreading, but he latter sounds tastier.

Comment: Spreading is the terminology used in most other languages, I'm not sure what the preference in Python is.

Answer (score -1):

Example solution

```
# list of lists
numbers = [[1.2, 3.4, 2.2], [5.6, 3.4, 2.1], [3.2, 2.8, 7.2]]

def add(x,y,z):
    return x+y+z

my_dict = dict()
my_dict["key"] = [add(num_list[0], num_list[1], num_list[2]) for num_list in numbers]

print("my_dict =", my_dict)
```

**Output:**

```
my_dict = {'key': [6.8, 11.1, 13.2]}
```

Comment: Why do you need a function `add` that does the same thing as `sum`? But the question wants to call a function that takes 3 separate arguments, not a list.

Comment: I'm just trying to give a simple solution with the `add` function. I was brainstorming to give you a simple solution and got a downvote instead. I have edited my code that now takes 3 separate arguments. Hope that helps.